# How retrieve coordinates in same order?

Tags: swift, firebase, mapkit

```
"-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG0" : {
  "coordinates" : {
    "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG1" : {
      "latitude" : 13.17078652595298,
      "longitude" : -59.5775944578738
    },
    "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG2" : {
      "latitude" : 13.15541190861343,
      "longitude" : -59.57619643155932
    },
    "-KHbCuQg9W_tebl1pU66" : {
      "latitude" : 13.148444967591,
      "longitude" : -59.5589266947333
    }
  },
  "subtitle" : "patrick",
  "title" : "River",
  "type" : "polyline"
},
```

This is my JSON structure for saving polylines and I need retrieve coordinates in same order.

This is my code for obtaining coordinates and creating polylines.

```
// geoobject.key - is ID of geoobject (for loop geoobjects) "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG0" 
    DataService.dataService.getGeoObject(geoobject.key).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { geoSnapshot in
                    var coordinatesPolyline = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
                        if let geoDictionary = geoSnapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                        let id = geoSnapshot.key
                                if geoDictionary["type"] as! String == "polyline" {
                                            if let coords = geoDictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]] {
                                                let contents = coords.values
                                                for content in contents {
                                                    let latitude = content["latitude"]
                                                    let longitude = content["longitude"]
                                                    let point = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
                                                    coordinatesPolyline.append(point)
                                            }
                                                // coordintesPolyline contains shuffle coordinates
                                                let polyline = Polyline(coordinates: &coordinatesPolyline, count: coordinatesPolyline.count)
                                                //coordinates = []
                                                polyline.id = geoSnapshot.key
                                                polyline.title = geoDictionary["title"] as? String
                                                polyline.subtitle = geoDictionary["subtitle"] as? String
                                                self.polylines.insert(polyline, atIndex: 0)
                                }
                        }
                    })
```

I rendered polylines but polylines are renderder bad because coordinates are shuffle.

Does anyone know how to get coordinates in the correct order. Firebase retrieve coordinates shuffle and then rendering doesn't work well.

Thank you for some advice.

Comment: why doesn't your JSON contain an array?

Comment: Is it big problem? I create this dictionary structure.

Comment: dictionaries don't have an order, so you'd need to serially parse the JSON to know the order...

Comment: Please I need some advice, I can't change saving coordinates with array.

Comment: you'll need to find a JSON parser that allows you to do stream parsing so you can process the items during the parse

Comment: Please don't use Firebase arrays for this - it will get you into trouble. When you say 'they are shuffle' what does that mean? With .Value, Firebase data will load in the order they appear in firebase, in this case it looks like the nodes are created with .childByAutoId which will be sequential in the order they were created. Can you tell us what order you would like them in?

Comment: @Wain While it's correct that dictionaries do not have an order, Firebase JSON data can be ordered in a number of ways without parsing. orderByKey, orderByValue and orderByChild loads data sequentially by those parameters. So if the key is for example a date (or a key created by childByAutoId), orderingByKey will load those nodes in date order.

Comment: Shuffle mean for me: coordintesnolyline (array) contains coordinates in different order than in Firebase database.

Comment: so presumably that's locally sorted data @Jay ? I know little about Firebase, interested to know what trouble the arrays cause

Comment: @Wain No - Firebase handles the query parameters at the server level and sorts and sends data based on how the query is constructed. Arrays cannot be queried (well, kinda) and individual elements cannot be updated, the entire node has to be re-written. In general there are better routes for Firebase structures than arrays.

Comment: I used orderByKey now it doesn't work. Dictionaries polylines are sorted but coordinates dictionaries (nested) are not.

Comment: If you order by key, then (based on the data in your structure) the first node will be -KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG1, the second will be -KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG2. Those are the keys, and that's the order they are read in. Each node in the snapshot doesn't have any nested dictionaries themselves, just two child nodes; long and lat. As a test, I would suggest commenting out all the code within the block and replace it with a simple print(snapshot.value) statement and check the console for output. It should be in the order I just mentioned.

Comment: Whoops. I overlooked a coding issue - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When reading firebase data by .Value, ALL of the data within the node is returned in the snapshot.

If you want the data in a specific order, you need to decide what 'thing' you want it ordered by. The natural order is by key, but if you want it ordered by some other parameter, you need to include that in you firebase structure, and then add orderedBy to your observe.

One you have the data by .Value, you then need to iterate over each child within the snapshot to access that nodes data. For example

If your Firbase structure is

```
"coordinates" : {
    "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG1" : {
      "latitude" : 13.17078652595298,
      "longitude" : -59.5775944578738
    },
    "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG2" : {
      "latitude" : 13.15541190861343,
      "longitude" : -59.57619643155932
    },
    "-KHbCuQg9W_tebl1pU66" : {
      "latitude" : 13.148444967591,
      "longitude" : -59.5589266947333
    }
```

Then the snapshot contains All of that data. Iterate over the snapshot and work with each child:

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { geoSnapshot in

   for child in geoSnapshot.children {
       let lat = child["latitude"] as? String
       let long = child["longitude"] as? String

       print("lat = \(lat)   long = \(long)"
   }
})
```

(didn't test that code but it's close)

Oh, and one other thing. ObserveEventOfType(.Value) will continually observe the node for changes - add, change or remove and will fire any time one of those events occur.

If you just want a one-shot, use ObserveSingleEventOfType(.Value)